# How to panTo/setCenter on a OpenLayers GeometryPoint

Tags: openlayers

First, I'm new to OpenLayers. The following is a snippet ot HTML used to represent a couple of images on a map rendered via OpenLayers. QUESTION: using the information below how can I programmatically bring one of these image elements into view? I.e., I think I'd like to **panTo** or **setCenter** on one of these elements. This is part of a test script where I find the images, bring them one-by-one into view and take some action on them.  The from projection is EPS6:4326 and the to projection is EPS6:900913.  Thanks.

```
<svg id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_98_svgRoot" style="display: block;" width="1663" height="301" viewBox="0 0 1663 301">
    <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_98_root" style="visibility: visible;" transform="translate(-33.02402040717425,-1.0000000016589183)">
    <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_98_vroot">
        <image id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_106" cx="458.11467034582165" cy="220.41962755130953" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="432" y="195" width="51.28563443264394" height="51.28563443264394" xlink:href="http://MyURL/service/maps/getDetails/../chart?cht=pc&chco=ee3324CC|ed8000CC&chd=t:78,22&chs=150x150&chf=bg,s,00000000,o,4,00000040" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        <image id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_108" cx="622.4436271582672" cy="115.50492808134004" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="594" y="87" width="57.54611514812745" height="57.54611514812745" xlink:href="http://MyURL/service/maps/getDetails/../chart?cht=pc&chco=ee3324CC|ed8000CC&chd=t:0,100&chs=150x150&chf=bg,s,00000000,o,4,00000040" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        <image id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_110" cx="437.6028635396797" cy="115.08515270121279" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="412" y="90" width="50.648406931246505" height="50.648406931246505" xlink:href="http://MyURL/service/maps/getDetails/../chart?cht=p&chco=ee3324CC|ed8000CC&chd=t:0,100&chs=150x150&chf=bg,s,00000000,o,4,00000040" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </g>
        <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_98_troot"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is generated code, no? Because openlayers uses SVG (except on IE) for rendering vectors, but you don't usually create them directly like this. It is reasonably easy to panTo a geometry. Could you post an example in jsfiddle.

Comment: This HTML is generated ... yes. What I need to be able to do, as part of testing, is cause one of these points to become visible on the screen. I'm assuming that all I know is the information in the HTML and the from and to transforms of the map. So, for example, knowing the above, how would I panTo OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_110?